# How to plot a hazard function?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I would like to plot a hazard function when the CDF and PDF are not in the closed form. The PDF and CDF are given below

```
pdf[μ_, σ_, λ_, α_, β_] := ProbabilityDistribution[
    (1/(E^(y^2/2)*(σ*Sqrt[2*Pi]*(α + 2))))*(2 + (α*Integrate[
        1/(E^(u^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi])/E^(u^2/2)
        , {u, -Infinity, λ*y + β*Sqrt[1 + λ^2]}])/Integrate[
            E^(-(v^2/2))
            , {v, -Infinity, β}
            ]
        )
    , {y, -Infinity, Infinity}
]
```

CDF has the form of

```
cdf[μ_, σ_, λ_, α_, β_] := (1/(E^(y^2/2)*(Sqrt[2*Pi]*(α + 2))))*(2 + α/2/((1/Sqrt[2*Pi])*Integrate[
    E^(-(v^2/2))
    , {v, -Infinity, β}
    ])) - ((α/(α + 2))*Integrate[
          (1/(E^(u^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi]))*(1/(E^(v^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi]))
          , {u, x, Infinity}
          , {v, 0, λ*y + β*Sqrt[1 + λ^2]}])/ ((1/Sqrt[2*Pi])*Integrate[E^(-(v^2/2))
          , {v, -Infinity, β}
      ]
)
```

Comment: Next time ask: Did you give us enough to work on your problem? For which values for all these parameters do you want to plot? What is the problem you are facing? Why don you evaluate your integrals? For example `Integrate[E^(-(v^2/2)), {v, -Infinity, β}]` can be replaced  with `Sqrt[Pi/2] (1 + Erf[β/Sqrt[2]]) `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`HazardFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HazardFunction.html).

Do not confuse a PDF with a [`ProbabilityDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html)

```
pdf[μ_, σ_, λ_, α_, β_, y_] = FullSimplify[
    (1/(E^(y^2/2)*(σ*Sqrt[2*Pi]*(α + 2))))*(2 + (α*Integrate[
        1/(E^(u^2/2)*Sqrt[2*Pi])/E^(u^2/2)
        , {u, -Infinity, λ*y + β*Sqrt[1 + λ^2]}])/Integrate[
            E^(-(v^2/2))
            , {v, -Infinity, β}
            ]
    )
]
```

[image]

Build you Hazard Function nesting [`HazardFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HazardFunction.html) and [`ProbabilityDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html) on you PDF.

```
myHazard[μ_, σ_, λ_, α_, β_][z_?NumericQ] := N[
    HazardFunction[
        ProbabilityDistribution[
            pdf[μ, σ, λ, α, β, y]
            , {y, -Infinity, Infinity}
            ]
        , z
    ]
]
```

Now you need to provide parameters and [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) your [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html)

```
$PlotTheme = {"Scientific", "VibrantColor", "BoldScheme", "LargeLabels"};
Plot[
    Evaluate@Flatten@Table[
        myHazard[μ, σ, λ, α, β][z]
        , {μ, {1}}
        , {σ, {1}}
        , {λ, {-1, 1}}
        , {α, {1}}
        , {β, {-5}}
    ]
    , {z, -10,50}
    , PlotLegends-> Automatic
]
```

[image]

Comment: `NIntegrate[pdf[1, 1, 1, 1, -5, y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]` does not equal `1`. The `pdf` has not been normalized.

Comment: @BobHanlon Yeah, you are right I noticed, but that wasn't the core of the question, I think. There is no information about the parameters domain, some don't even appear on the expression.

Comment: That is one of the benefits of using `ProbabilityDistribution`, you can add `Method -> "Normalize"`, e.g., `dist = ProbabilityDistribution[pdf[\[Mu], \[Sigma], \[Lambda], \[Alpha], \[Beta], y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, Method -> "Normalize", Assumptions -> {\[Sigma] > 0, \[Alpha] > -2, {\[Beta], \[Lambda]} \[Element] Reals}]` (although I am just guessing at the appropriate `Assumptions` on the parameters). The `PDF` is then `PDF[dist, y]`

Comment: @BobHanlon I think the OP should ponder about just forcing normalization or finding the error on his definition of a PDF that doesn't integrate into 1. I wouldn't just "fix" the PDF without further thought.